# Prime $p$ whose period of reciprocal equals $(p-1)/10$

Tags: nt.number-theory

$18671$ is a Prime $p$ whose period of reciprocal equals $(p-1)/10.$

Have these numbers some relevance, some special property?

Comment: This is equivalent to $10$ having order $(p-1)/10$ modulo $p$. I don't think this on its own has much relevance, but it's closely related to the [Artin's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%27s_conjecture_on_primitive_roots) on primes for which $10$ is a primitive root, which is equivalent to the reciprocal having period $p-1$.

Comment: These primes are tabulated at https://oeis.org/A056215 where no special properties are noted.